# Expectation or Integration of the normal cdf

Tags: calculus, statistics, multivariable-calculus, discrete-mathematics, statistical-inference

Can any one help me how to solve this pronbelm?

I have a random variable $W$, i.e.,

$$W=\Phi(X)^k\Phi(-X)^m=P(Z\le X)^kP(Z \ge X)^m,$$ $X$ is Normal($\mu$,1), $Z \text{ is Normal(0,1)}$, and $k$ and $m$ are two constant integers.

I want to find the expectation of $W$, which is $EW$. In other words I want to find the integration of
$$\int \Phi(x)^k\Phi(-x)^mf(x)dx$$

a) I tried to find first the density function of $W$ like the following way and then $EW$ but could not solve:

$$P(W\le w)=P\left(\Phi(X)^k\Phi(Y)^m\le w\right)=\int P\left(X\le \Phi^{-1} \left( \left( \frac{w}{\Phi(y)^m} \right)^{1/k} \right)\right) f(y)\,dy$$

b) I also tried like
$$W=\Phi(X)^k\Phi(-X)^m=P(Z\le X)^kP(Z \ge X)^m=P(Z-X\le 0)^kP(Z-X \ge 0)^m=\Phi \left(\frac{-\mu}{\sqrt(2-2\rho)}\right)^k\Phi \left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt(2+2\rho)}\right)^m.$$ Since $Z-X \text{ is Normal(-$\mu,2-2\rho$) if correlation between Z and X is $\rho.$  }$ 
Therfore, $$EW=\Phi \left(\frac{-\mu}{\sqrt(2-2\rho)}\right)^k\Phi \left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt(2+2\rho)}\right)^m.$$ 
Is the second procedure right?

Thank you I highly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean the distribution of the product of two normal random variables?

Comment: no. i mean distribution of W

Comment: I don't understand...distributions don't have a distribution. Note that $\Phi$ takes all values between $0$ and $1$ so $\Phi^k\Phi^m$ is autmoatically a distribution function.

Comment: Mainly, a notation issue is to use capital letter for random variable. Do you mean you want to find out the distribution of $W = \Phi(X)^k\Phi(-X)^m$? And the distribution of $X$ is also not specified yet?

Comment: @BGM Yes you were right. Thank you

Comment: If μ=0, EW is a multiple of some rank related probability for an i.i.d. standard normal sample of size k+m+1 hence the value of EW is direct. Otherwise the result is most probably a mess.